# Refresh View in MVC asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a view which has different sections displaying different type of orders from DB (SQL Server). Now I need to refresh view with updated information each time a new order is submitted through Android Application. Below are code snippets:

ViewModel:

```
public class KitchenViewModel
{
    public List<Orders> DisplayOrders { get; set; }
    public List<Orders> PreparedOrders { get; set; }
    public List<OrderItem> ProgressItems { get; set; }
    public List<OrderItem> QueuedItems { get; set; }
    public int DisplayOrdCount { get; set; }
    public int PreparedOrdCount { get; set; }
    public int QueuedOrdCount { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult KitchenOrder()
{
    KitchenModel kitchenInstance = new KitchenModel();

    List<Orders> orders = kitchenInstance.GetProgOrdersList();
    List<OrderItem> progressItems = kitchenInstance.GetItemProgress();
    List<OrderItem> queuedItems = kitchenInstance.GetItemQueued(); 
    List<Orders> prepOrders = kitchenInstance.GetPrepOrdersList();
    List<Orders> queuedOrders = kitchenInstance.GetQueuedOrdersList();
    KitchenViewModel viewModel = new KitchenViewModel();
    viewModel.PreparedOrders = prepOrders;
    viewModel.ProgressItems = progressItems;
    viewModel.DisplayOrders = orders;
    viewModel.QueuedItems = queuedItems;
    viewModel.DisplayOrdCount = orders.Count;
    viewModel.PreparedOrdCount = prepOrders.Count;
    viewModel.QueuedOrdCount = queuedOrders.Count;
    return View(viewModel);
}
```

As of now I am auto refreshing view after every 15 seconds which is working perfectly. 
But I need to refresh view only when a new order is submitted through Android application and order is inserted in DB. Once a new order is submitted the values for PreparedOrders, Progressitems, DisplayOrders gets changed and need to be fetched again. I have read many posts/tutorials relating to Observer pattern and publisher/subscriber method but unable to get crisp solution which would fit best. Could someone please provide relevant pointer/tutorial to use in such a scenario that could help. Being this my very first project and a total beginner, I m quite confused as in how to proceed.

Answer (score 2):

So if you have to update site on event that fires when something changes in base, as other clients have changed it, you need PUSH based architecture, and not PULL based like you do it now (requests on timer elapsed).

For this purpose you can use [SignalR](http://signalr.net/), that implements various modern communication mechanisms. The basic idea is: one time client accessed your site, there is a persistent 
connection created pointing to it's browser, and in the moment of notification you just roll over all available clients and notify them. On client side, naturally, event is handled in your case with `javascript`.

Worth mentioning that this technology has limitations across browser versioning, so refer to documentation to see if supported browser versions set satisfies your requirements.

Here is the link to supported platforms list for SignalR2: [Supported platforms](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/getting-started-with-signalr-20/supported-platforms)

Comment: Tigran hit this right on the nose and beat me to the punch. SignalR is a very nice library. That should definitely get you going.

Comment: @Damon: yes, but it depends on OP requirements. It's up to *him* to decide either use it or not.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Let me go through this and try as suggested.